# SQL Server grouping rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have this data:

```
     Id    | Name  | count |  Group_number      
     ------+-------+-------+--------------
     1     | cdd   |  50   |       0  
     2     | cdd   |  15   |       0  
     3     | cdd   |  0    |       0  
     4     | cdd   |  25   |       0   
     5     | cdd   |  11   |       0
```

I want a script that makes three or four groups on condition: Sum(count) for each group < 50

I want this output:

```
     1    | cdd    |  50    |      1  
     2    | cdd    |  15    |      2  
     3    | cdd    |  0     |      2  
     4    | cdd    |  25    |      2  
     5    | cdd    |  11    |      3
```

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: How is the data to be grouped? There doesn't seem to be anything that directly correlates the ids to the desired outputs?

Comment: can you please stipulate the group ranges. the OP is incomplete and if possible post the raw data

Comment: @ObsidianAge Looks like it's an incremental sum when sorted by ID. Each time you hit 50, you add a new group.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with summing to 50. That makes much more sense now ;)

Comment: @JNevill i reckon we are seeing an output rather the raw data

Comment: @maSTAShuFu why do you think that? "This data" and "this output" are clearly indicated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @JNevill exactly :)

Comment: been there done that scenario where you are presented with the supposed data but turned out to be an output

Comment: @MartinSmith 2014

Comment: Are you looking for a running total here? Like sum each row until you hit 50, then start again? Edit: comments are fast and furious here. I will assume that the answer is yes we're looking for a running total which resets at 50.

Comment: @JacobH I think it's a little more subtle then just "Hitting 50". If you hit more than 50, then the previous record ends the group and this record starts a new one. So it's up to and including "50" but not over 50.

Comment: @JacobH exactly :)

Comment: when the sum for tow rows is not 50 then he will see the third one and if it is not suitable he will take the fourth one etc.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this has to be done for each `name`, you can use a recursive cte.

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by name order by id) as rnum from t)
,cte(rnum,id,name,cnt,runningsum,grp) as  
(select rnum,id,name,cnt,cnt,1  from rownums where rnum=1
 union all
 select t.rnum,t.id,t.name,t.cnt
 ,case when c.runningsum+t.cnt > 50 then t.cnt else c.runningsum+t.cnt end
 ,case when c.runningsum+t.cnt > 50 then t.id else c.grp end
 from cte c
 join rownums t on t.rnum=c.rnum+1 and t.name=c.name
) 
select id,cnt,name,dense_rank() over(partition by name order by grp) as grp
from cte
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/YENI17952)

Keep track of the running sum and reset it when it goes over 50. Also remember the `id` when the sum goes over 50. This can be used to assign group numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For records where the count is less than 50 we can simply generate a grouping id by calculating a running total on the count and then divide this running total by 50.  However, since some records may already have a count that is greater than or equal to 50 might generate an incorrect id. To solve this problem, we need to somehow force the generation of a new grouping id on the next record.  This can be done by simply adjusting the count the next record by 50 if the current records count is 50 or greater.
The following example demonstrates how this can be done:

```
CREATE TABLE #Items
(
     [Id]       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Name]     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,[Count]    INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Items
VALUES 
(1, 'cdd', 50 ),         
(2, 'cdd', 15 ),       
(3, 'cdd', 0  ),        
(4, 'cdd', 25 ),         
(5, 'cdd', 11 );       

;WITH CTE_ItemCountsAdjusted
AS
(
    SELECT   [Id]       
            ,[Name] 
            ,[Count]
            ,LAG([Count], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id]) AS PrevCount
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN LAG([Count], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id]) >= 50 THEN [Count] + 50
                    ELSE [Count]
                END
            ) AdjustedCount
    FROM    #Items
)
SELECT   [Id]       
        ,[Name] 
        ,[Count]
        ,SUM([AdjustedCount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) / 50 AS [Group_number]
FROM    CTE_ItemCountsAdjusted
ORDER BY    [Id]
```

This method eliminates the need for recursive calls. Note if you need the group id to be strictly sequential (no gaps between group numbers) then you can make use of the DENSE_RANK() windowing function to achieve this as per following example:

```
INSERT INTO #Items
VALUES 
(1, 'cdd', 50 ),         
(2, 'cdd', 15 ),       
(3, 'cdd', 0  ),        
(4, 'cdd', 25 ),         
(5, 'cdd', 11 ),      
(6, 'cdd', 200 ),
(7, 'cdd', 10 );  

;WITH CTE_ItemCountsAdjusted
AS
(
    SELECT   [Id]       
            ,[Name] 
            ,[Count]
            ,LAG([Count], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id]) AS PrevCount
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN LAG([Count], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id]) >= 50 THEN [Count] + 50
                    ELSE [Count]
                END
            ) AdjustedCount
    FROM    #Items

),CTE_ItemCountsWithGroupID
AS
(
    SELECT   [Id]       
            ,[Name] 
            ,[Count]
            ,SUM([AdjustedCount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Id] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) / 50 AS [Group_number]
    FROM    CTE_ItemCountsAdjusted  
)
SELECT   [Id]       
        ,[Name] 
        ,[Count]
        ,[Group_number]
```